# What is the advantage of Cypress commands over vanilla functions?

Tags: cypress

It is known that in Cypress we can define [custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Usage) in the `commands.js` file, with that syntax:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, pw) => {})
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (orig, url, options) => {})
```

These commands will then become available across all our tests and can be used from the `cy` object.

```js
cy.login('my@email.com', '123456')
cy.visit('www.stackoverflow.com', 'www.google.com', { redirect: true })
```

But I don't get the gist of it. What is the point of doing that when you could just write a regular function?

```js
function login(email, pw) { /* ... */ }

login('my@email.com', '123456')
```

The only advantage I see is making the function available everywhere without having to export/import it, but you can do that with globals as well. Is that it, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right! The goal is to write cleaner code and availability. With **custom commands** you can basically write the function in the form of a cypress command and also you don't have to write an import statement in the tests suites. Hence your test suite files remain uniform and cleaner.

Comment: I'd also add something about adding them to the Cypress chain, which mean they'l execute in the correct order when mixed with other Cypress commands. Using vanilla JS functions interspersed with Cypress functions can have unpredictable/unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 5):

**1. Don't make everything a custom command**.
Don't be forget cypress provide API for **overwriting existing commands** not for only creating new commands.
JS function is great for grouping cy commands and preferable due to it simplicity and readability.

There’s no reason to add this level of complexity when you’re only wrapping a couple of commands only for avoiding Export/Import.

**2. Don't overcomplicate things.**
A good test automation framework will be is easily understandable, readable and maintainable.Try not to overcomplicate things and create too many abstractions. When in doubt, Always use a JS function.

check out here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Best-Practices